# Got a scrollable div, draggables still get dropped on hidden elements?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, scroll

ok i've got a scrollable div, but when i drag my draggable outside of that overflowed div and try and drop it on a different drop zone. it gets dropped onto the hidden elements underneath the drop zone i want it to get applied to. is there any to give the drop that i can see "priority" ?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you remove the class that designates that the element is a "dropzone" from the hidden elements.

also, more info might be nice for a better answer

Comment: well the elements aren't necessarily hidden, they are just hidden if you haven't scrolled over to them yet. i apologize for not giving enough info. i thought enough was given. but anyways, even if you just have to scroll over to the "hidden" elements, they don't have any different css do they? how would i determine if they were hidden or not in the javascript?